# How to find library installation timestamp in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Is there any way to check the installation date and time for a library installed in DataBricks cluster ?

Comment: Maybe tangential, but can you elaborate as to *why* this is important information for you? I think there's a possibility that if you can provide this additional context, there may be alternative ways to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Hi @esqew I have scheduled jobs running in databricks randomly it throws module not found error for the libraries installed in cluster. My assumption is that the installation takes time to complete where my job starts prior so it is failing with module not found error where else all the jobs starting 30 min later the cluster starts succeeded. Only the jubs starting first when the cluster starts fails wih this message.

Comment: are you using existing cluster?

Comment: Yes it is interactive cluster and all libraries are pre-installed through libraries tab

Comment: Every time you start the cluster, the libraries are installed.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned that it works when after half hour then you can try to put an exception handling at start of your code instead of looking for time the library is installed

something like

```
def toc(s):
  import time
  try:
    #Put some module import which would fail without library
    
  except Exception as e :
    s+=1 
    if s<10:   #set max number of tries so that it fails in 1 hour if library still not found
      print (s,str(e))
      toc(s)
    time.sleep(300)  #Check for it each 5 min
      
 toc(0) #function call
```